# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem is this example a valid use case?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I need to send out a batch of reminder emails, never more than 100 emails per batch, using authenticated SMTP. This is happening on a WindowsService (no GUI).

The SMTP library we're using raises a **Sent** event. In the Sent eventlistener, we grab some info from the Sent event's `args` and write some data to a SqlServer database via SqlClient library, to note the fact that the particular email has been sent to the recipient, and when it went out.

Is there any concern or issue for the Sent eventlistener when the emails are being sent out on multiple threads managed by ThreadPool?

pseudocode:

```
  for each record in batch
     {
       var email = buildEmail(record);
       ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( a =>
            {
               if (!SmtpClient.Connected) SmtpClient.Connect();
               if (!SmtpClient.Authenticated) SmtpClient.Authenticate();
               if (SmtpClient.Authenticated) SmtpClient.Send(email);
            }); 
     }


   SmtpClient.Sent += (sender, args) =>
  {
          //get info from args
          // populate SqlCommand parameters

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(b =>
           {
               UpdateDatabase(info);
           });
  };
```

Comment: Does it work? ..

Comment: Yes, it appears to work, but it's not been stress-tested, and I'm not sure if there are conditions where it wouldn't work. I haven't used ThreadPool before, and don't know if there could be some kind of side-effect of adding a work item to the queue from within a listener to an event which was raised from a work item in the pool.

Comment: I would worry about a) silent dropping exceptions b) application/scope exit before all items processed

Comment: also, not clear in your code, but are they all using a single static SmtpClient and Database? in which case, does running send in multiple separate threads actually help?

Answer (score 1):

From the code it looks like it should work.  Spinning off queued threads to the thread pool from an event listener should not cause issues (and I use a similar pattern is some of my code).

You will want to stress test the code to make sure that through put is enough to keep up and I would read up on error handling in multi threaded code (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218080/c-sharp-threadpool-queueuserworkitem-exception-handling for example).

Another pain point you will want to look out for is Connection Pool exhaustion.  When you queue up your background threads if you have enough cpu capacity (or code UpdateDatabase using `async` to release the thread while waiting) you can try to open more connections to the database than there are in the connection pool.  When I was writing code very similar to yours I ran into issues with this and had to batch the actual updates to the database.